# Win Server 2016 - Event ID = 300, X509 store location WindowsPowerShell is not valid

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, powershell-v5.0

I have a Windows Server 2016 (Build 14393) that I'm running NPrinting on (possibly not relevant). I performed an update on Friday night, and I am seeing EventID=300 errors.  Below is the full text of the warning.

```
Provider Health: Cannot find the certificate store 
because the specified X509 store 
location WindowsPowerShell is not valid.. 

Details: 
    ProviderName=Certificate
    ExceptionClass=ProviderInvocationException
    ErrorCategory=ObjectNotFound
    ErrorId=CertProviderItemNotFound
    ErrorMessage=Cannot find the certificate store because 
      the specified X509 store 
      location WindowsPowerShell is not valid.
    Severity=Warning
    SequenceNumber=109
    HostName=Default Host
    HostVersion=5.1.14393.3866
    HostId=49853eaf-740f-437f-b361-bb0b40af7e66
    HostApplication=C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiprvse.exe
    EngineVersion=5.1.14393.3866
    RunspaceId=19286b5f-7eb9-45bb-b26d-8fddbc61a25b
    PipelineId=132
```

I've noticed that the errors only flood in when my `Powershell ISE` (Powershell 5.1.14393.3866) is open.  And boy, do they flood in.

[image: Powershell failing issue]

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This Warning is coming from PowerShell telling you the Certificate provider failed to load.

PowerShell has a "provider" built into Windows that connects `cert:` to the certificate stores on your computer so you can manipulate certificates in PowerShell easily. Here's a detailed explanation with examples https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/about/about_certificate_provider?view=powershell-7

As far as I'm aware, there are only two valid Store Locations: CurrentUser and LocalMachine

You can see these with `Get-ChildItem cert: | Format-List *`

```
PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser
PSParentPath  :
PSChildName   : CurrentUser
PSDrive       : Cert
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate
PSIsContainer : True
LocationName  : CurrentUser
Location      : CurrentUser
StoreNames    : {SmartCardRoot, Root, Trust, AuthRoot...}

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine
PSParentPath  :
PSChildName   : LocalMachine
PSDrive       : Cert
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate
PSIsContainer : True
LocationName  : LocalMachine
Location      : LocalMachine
StoreNames    : {TestSignRoot, ClientAuthIssuer, Remote Desktop, Root...}
```

Your error says PowerShell is trying to open the Location named `WindowsPowerShell` and can't find it because it's not valid. That makes sense, since there is no location with that name.

I would start by checking which Locations you see in the `cert:` drive. You mention the errors pop up when you start ISE, do you have any Add-Ons in ISE? A code-signing add-in with a bug could be trying to open the wrong location and cause this error.